# Is there a way to split stream into 2 list in one go?

Tags: java

My goal is to create a dependency injection similar to Spring Framework. Right now, I am trying to scan all of the classes within a package, and the subpackages.

My requirements:

```
Input: a package name.
Output: all of the classes from the package and the subpackages.
```

I built a recursion to scan the tree. It works as expected.

I noticed that the code iterate a list twice `create a stream -> convert it to list without filter, to get the Resources -> create a stream -> convert it to list with filter, to get the packageNames`.

```
  private List<String> getResources(String packageName) {
    InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream(packageName.replaceAll("[.]", "/"));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    return bufferedReader.lines()
            .map(i -> packageName.concat("." + i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  private List<String> getPackages(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(i -> !i.endsWith(".class"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  private List<String> getTreeWithRecursion(String packageName) {
    List<String> list = getResources(packageName);
    List<String> packageNames = getPackages(list);
```

My expected result: I can `.collect(Collectors.toList())` into 2 list `classes` and `packages`.

My actual result: `stream` only can be collected once.

Full code

```
public class AccessingAllClassesInPackage {
  private List<String> getResources(String packageName) {
    InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream(packageName.replaceAll("[.]", "/"));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    return bufferedReader.lines()
            .map(i -> packageName.concat("." + i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  private List<String> getPackages(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(i -> !i.endsWith(".class"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  private List<String> getTreeWithRecursion(String packageName) {
    List<String> list = getResources(packageName);
    List<String> packageNames = getPackages(list);
    if (packageNames.size() > 0) {
      for (String aPackageName : packageNames) {
        list.addAll(getTreeWithRecursion(aPackageName)); // recursion
      }
    }
    return list;
  }

  protected Class getClass(String className) {
    try {
      return Class.forName(
              className.substring(0, className.lastIndexOf('.')));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // handle the exception
    }
    return null;
  }

  public List<Class> getAllClasses(String parentPackageName) {
    List<String> list = getTreeWithRecursion(parentPackageName);
    return list.stream()
            .filter(i -> i.endsWith(".class"))
            .map(this::getClass)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

Comment: you can try using Collectors.groupingBy if its simple to group your list according to a rule and return a Map<K,List<V>.

Comment: here you can find out more about available collectors: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html

Comment: @meaningqo i tried it with `Collectors.groupingBy()` and get the list by `map.get()`. However, `map.get()` may return null, and this cause the code to throw `NullFointerexception`. Is there a way for `map.get()` to return empty `List`, so I can still call `list.size()`. Currently I use `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Comment: Is `Collectors.partioningBy` what you want? It does guarantee an empty list when there is nothing in that group. But why are you using a `Map<String, List<String>>`? Shouldn't it be a `Map<Boolean, List<String>>` - one group for classes, the other group for packages?

Comment: @Sweeper i think it's for better readability, instead of calling `get(true)`, I can call `get("classNames")`? or does this gives performance penalty? ps: current test shows, the spread range over required time increased 2x if I use `String` rather than `Boolean` for the Key, but currently my computer is running hot, so the test is rather not trustworthy.

Comment: Oh so you are just using two constant strings for your keys. That makes sense. I didn't understand your last sentence. Which one has the worse performance according to the test?

Comment: @Sweeper the one that use String `Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.endsWith(".class") ? "classNames" : "packageNames")`. I see you suggest `partitioninBy`. I will try it, please give me a minute.

Comment: [`Collectors.partitioningBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate))

Answer (score 2):

Thank to @meaningqo and @Sweeper. This is the current code I use.

getResources

```
    return bufferedReader.lines()
            .map(i -> packageName.concat("." + i))
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(i -> i.endsWith(".class")));
```

getTreeWithRecursion

```
    Map<Boolean, List<String>> resources = getResources(packageName);
    List<String> classNames = resources.get(true);
    List<String> packageNames = resources.get(false);
```