# Is there a way to stream().collect() 1 item into 2 groups?

Tags: java, java-stream

My goal is to group classes within a package and subpackages into `Map<ClassAnnotationType, List<Class> map`. @usage e.g `map.get(ClassAnnotationType.RestController)`

What I've done:

1. Get all classes within a package and subpackages. [Stack Overflow's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68494456/is-there-a-way-to-split-stream-into-2-list-in-one-go?noredirect=1#comment121051190_68494456)

ClassAnnotationType

```
public enum ClassAnnotationType {
  RestController,
  Service,
  Unknown
}
```

List of Class Annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface RestController{
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Service {
}
```

This is how the search tree would work

```
  /**
   * .class .class package                              package
   *                 / \ (first iteration)                / \ (second iteration)
   *        .class .class package                 .class .class package
   *                        / \ (first iteration)                 / \ (second iteration)
   */
```

This is the line of code I wish to change

```
  private Map<Boolean, List<String>> getResources(String packageName) {
    InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream(packageName.replaceAll("[.]", "/"));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    return bufferedReader.lines()
            .map(i -> packageName.concat("." + i))
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(i -> i.endsWith(".class")));
  }
```

into something like this

```
.collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(i -> {
          for (Annotation annotation : i.getAnnotations()) {
            // add the Class to the key.
          }
        }));
```

My expected result: Collectors.groupingBy() can add 1 item `class Hello` into 2 different groups e.g `RestController, Service`

My actual result: 1 item for 1 group.

Current pre-solution

```
.collect(i -> {
  if (i.isAnnotationPresent(RestController.class)) {
    return ClassAnnotationType.RestController;
  }
  return ClassAnnotationType.Unknown; // i wish not to do this.
});
```

This created problems:

1. 1 class only can exists in 1 group.
2. Due to the nature of `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` it will return `class class package` within a package. The current code has to list the tree first and map it into String before type casting it to `Class` using the `Class.forName()` method. In other words, the only viable way is to do it in three steps. a. get all the class within a package and subpackages with recursion to a `List<String>` b. type cast it to `List<Class>` c. map it to `Map<ClassAnnotationType, List<Class>`.
3. All of the classes need to be mapped into a key, including the class without annotation `return ClassAnnotationType.Unknown`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a custom `Collector`, with [`Collector.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-). Perhaps something like:

```
Collector.of(
    // Supplier.
    HashMap::new,

    // Accumulator.
    (map, i) -> {
          // Your code. You can put whatever you like into the map,
          // so you can put something in for multiple keys.
          for (Annotation annotation : i.getAnnotations()) {
            // add the Class to the key.
          }
    },

    // Combiner.
    (map1, map2) -> { map1.putAll(map2); return map1; }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve it, but perhaps better explained with a simpler and reproducible example.

Suppose you had the following two Integer lists:

```
List<Integer> numbers = List.of(2, 3);
List<Integer> multiples = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
```

And you wanted to map each *multiple* to each of its *divisors*, grouping those that don't have a corresponding divisor under key *-1*. A number like `6` would have to show up in the mapping for both 2 and 3.

Here's one solution for it:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = numbers.stream()
    .map(div -> Map.entry(div, multiples.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(e -> 0 == e % div))))
    .flatMap(partitions -> List.of(
            Map.entry(partitions.getKey(), partitions.getValue().get(true)), 
            Map.entry(-1, partitions.getValue().get(false))
        ).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Entry::getKey, 
            Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(), 
                                   Collectors.toList())));
```

Which will produce

```
{-1=[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11], 
  2=[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], 
  3=[3, 6, 9, 12]}
```

Now, there's clearly a problem with the `-1` values, which are the union of all values that failed to be divided by any number.

I didn't see a clean way to resolve it but by using the following cleanup code:

```
Set<Integer> foundDivisors = new HashSet<>(map.getOrDefault(-1, new ArrayList<>()));
map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(div -> !div.getKey().equals(-1))
    .forEach(entry -> foundDivisors.removeAll(entry.getValue()));
map.replace(-1, new ArrayList<>(foundDivisors));
```

And the result is `map` has the expected values:

```
{-1=[1, 5, 7, 11], 
  2=[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], 
  3=[3, 6, 9, 12]}
```

---

You can use the same logic with your code. I couldn't test it, but it would roughly look like this:

```
//maps enum to scanned annotation
enum ClassAnnotationType {
    REST_CONTROLLER(RestController.class), 
    SERVICE(Service.class), 
    UNKNOWN(null)
    // constructor, etc.
}


Map<ClassAnnotationType, List<Class<?>>> map = Arrays.stream(ClassAnnotationType.values())
    .filter(en -> en != ClassAnnotationType.UNKNOWN)
    .map(type -> Map.entry(type, yourClassList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(cls -> 
                cls.isAnnotationPresent(type.getAnnotationClass())))))
    .flatMap(partitions -> List.of(Map.entry(partitions.getKey(), partitions.getValue()
            .get(true)), Map.entry(ClassAnnotationType.UNKNOWN,
                    partitions.getValue().get(false))).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, 
             Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(), 
                     Collectors.toList())));
```

And then proceed with the removal of the value set for `ClassAnnotationType.UNKNOWN` as done above.

Comment: I can't do Java 9. I really appreciated it. I tried my best to understand the code. Is the logic correct? `.map` will loop through the divisors `2, 3` with the `multipliers` e.g `2 vs 1, 2 vs 2, 2 vs 3, ...`. This will return `Map<Integer, Map<Boolean, List<Integer>>` or `{2 = { false = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11], true = [ ] }, 3 = { false = [ ], true = [ ] } }`. And then, `.flatMap` will remap it and throw away the values with key `false` to the key of `-1` or `Map<Integer, List<Integer>` e.g. `{-1 = [], 2 = [], 3 = [] }` .

Comment: **The problem**: `-1` will be huge. But I think I get the idea, i will try to write down the logic on a piece of paper before writing the code. I think I will use `for` loop for a while. `stream()` is too much for me :( and I heard it's not thread safe, am I right?